# Node Js get post data as json key

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, body-parser

> NodeJS File server.js

```
    var express     = require('express');
    var app         = express();
    var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
    var morgan      = require('morgan');
    var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
    var moment      = require('moment');
    var http        = require('http');
    var jwt         = require('jsonwebtoken'); 
    var config      = require('./config'); 
    var User        = require('./app/models/user'); 

    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080; 
    mongoose.connect(config.database);
    app.set('superSecret', config.secret); 
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.post('/onboardAuthentication', function(req, res) {
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
      res.setHeader('contentType', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;');  
      res.json(req.body);
    });
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

> Angular API Hit Code where Front side API hit

```
var serviceRoot='http://localhost:8080/onboardAuthentication';

            var deferred=$q.defer();

            var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: serviceRoot,
                data: { key: 'value' },
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            };

            $http(req).then(goodResponse,badResponse);

            return deferred.promise;

    function goodResponse(response)
    {
        console.log("Good response");
        console.log(response);

    }
    function badResponse(response)
    {
        console.log("Bad response");
        console.log(response.data);
    }
```

> It print result in this formate, it make post data as key and value is blank, but i want to access post data in json format using body-parsar node js.

```
{"key":"value"}: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send simple text/ ASCII data, then x-www-form-urlencoded will work,
by default angular will send application/json to the server.

```
var req = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: serviceRoot,
                data: { key: 'value' },
                // comment this line, you don't need it
                //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            };
```

Comment: still the issue exists, i think this issue from node js side

Comment: Object { data: "", status: 200, headers: qd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "OK" }

Comment: Remove also res.setHeader('contentType', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;');

Comment: removed same result  {"key":"value"}: "" get data in object formate

Comment: Hey please run the same code and check way this happen,  I think this issue related to body-parse